# Which Circuit Does this Switchbox Common Wire Belong To?

Tags: lighting, smart-switch, common-wire

I'm replacing a single-pole switch with a Lutron Caseta, in a switch box that houses two switches, each on a different circuit. The old switch that I've removed was connected to two wires: line (red wire) and load (green wire)[image] from one circuit. The switch on the other circuit, that I'm leaving as-is is still connected in the photos. Since I need a common wire for my new Lutron switch, I'm hopeful to see a neutral in the back of the box. But I'm not sure which circuit this neutral belongs to. Is there a way to check this, or would trial-and-error suffice? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: If it's a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit, *possibly both.* Are the breakers next to each other in the panel? What's the age of the place? Modern MWBCs need to be handle-tied or dual breaker, earlier they did not. Otherwise, you are **in conduit,** look at the light, pull a neutral from there. Looks blue from here, green would be a code violation...

Comment: That's a blue wire.  You're not allowed to use green for anything but ground.

Comment: Breakers aren't adjacent: breakers 1 and 5. Electric was updated with 150 amp service appx. 1995. And yes--that wire is blue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no such thing as "common" in AC mains wiring.  Each circuit is wired in a full loop**.  If you do automotive wiring, you tend to think of the metal vehicle chassis as the "common" all current returns to.  Or in electronics you have the Vss backplane.  Those concepts do not apply in AC mains.  All circuits are full out-and-back with a dedicated neutral *per circuit*.

### That neutral belongs with the other circuit.

You can tell because of NEC 300.3, which requires all related wires to be in the same cable or conduit.  (mainly to assure the magnetic fields thrown by currents are equal and opposite, so the fields cancel each other out, because AC magnetic fields are serious business.)

Take a close look at the top conduit.  It has 1 hot wire (blue) and one neutral wire (white) and no other wires.  Therefore, that neutral can only possibly be with the blue, and therefore, it is only with the two orange *travelers* in what is surely a 3-way setup.  The red and the "other blue" are clearly a **switch loop** coming from another source.  That switch's neutral needs to come from that source.

### You need to fish a separate neutral.

You will need to go to the destination of that (red-partnered) blue wire and fish a neutral wire.  You must clearly identify it; you can't have two "mystery white wires" in a box.   Many stores sell 5-packs of colored electrical tape in the $5 range.

For the neutral wire, you can hunt down gray wire by-the-foot (good luck: only electrical supply houses sell gray, and few sell it by-the-foot, and they don't sell short spools, and a 500' spool will be $90.)  However you are more likely to find white THHN in sane quantity.  That will require colored electrical tape or shrink tube to mark your neutrals (and I advise: your blue switched-hots).

In conduit, when you mark a white wire with colored tape, that does *not* mark it as a hot wire, it simply associates it with a hot wire. This is necessary, because there are only 2 allowed neutral colors (white and gray) yet up to 4 circuits can be in a conduit, with 8 legal hot wire colors.

### Other notes

Despite appearances, you are fully grounded. EMT metal conduit has a metal shell which is an approved grounding path (when installed correctly). Switches auto-ground via the mounting screws (though if the yoke is plastic, and it has a ground *wire*, you may need to run it to a #10-32 ground screw, which a hole in the back of the box is tapped for.

It's possible these two circuits are combined as a *multi-wire branch circuit*. If so, then they are sharing the neutral, but we can't assume that because being wrong about that would be pretty dangerous. Identifying it as an MWBC would require finding a doubled-up breaker, turning it off and seeing both circuits shut off at once.

Comment: Thanks @ecnerwal, I missed that double orange.

Comment: I did at first, myself.

Comment: 500' of copper _anything_ for only $90 seems like a pretty good deal these days!

Comment: Excellent insights and advice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The neutral is clearly from the circuit you are not changing the switch on, as it goes into and comes out of conduits with the [hot or switched hot - blue] and travelers (orange) connected to that [3-way] switch.